# Dynamically calculating size of RecyclerView populated with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` **inside a `ScrollView`**. As you **can't set `WRAP_CONTENT`** parameter for `RecylerView` (doesn't support it), I have to calculate the height of view, dynamically. (Adapter gets populated dynamically. Its an infinite scroll view). You can find similar behavior in **Pinterest** app. (Pictured below). I also wrote my layout view hierarchy.

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <some_layouts>
     .
     .
    </some_layouts>  
    <RecyclerView>
    </RecyclerView>  
  <LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

How can I get same thing in my app? I dug through the classes api but found nothing. Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although answer is too late and i was also finding the solution i came across the library in which size of the item layout is dynamically adjusted with few lines of code.

Just add

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'

}
```

[Github Library Link](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Use below code:-

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(getContext());
                layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

So you don't have calculate height dynamically.